# Jade and Express.js - req.body.[name of form] is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, dropdown

I'm trying to update a database using a drop down form, but req.body.[name of form] is undefined.

req.body in console shows {}.

Here is my lev.js:

```
router.post('/kundeendring', function(req, res) {
    var test1 = req.body.ansvarlig;
    console.log(test1);
```

And here is the form in my lev.jade:

```
form#kunde(method="post", action="kundeendring")
    select (name= "ansvarlig")
        option(value='Kim', selected=kim) Kim 
        option(value='Christer', selected=christer) Christer
        option(value='Hege', selected=hege) Hege
        option(value='Morten', selected=morten) Morten
        option(value='Andre', selected=andre) Andre
    h3= "Lagre"
    button#btnSubmit(type="submit") submit
```

I also have bodyParser automatically installed using the express generator:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

When I click the submit button test1 is 'undefined'.

edit: Fixed a missing parentheses.

edit: This works in lev.jade, but still not able to transfer that to drop down:

```
form#formAddUser(name="adduser",method="post",action="kundeendring")
    input#inputUserName(type="text", placeholder="username", name="username")
    input#inputUserEmail(type="text", placeholder="useremail", name="useremail")
    button#btnSubmit(type="submit") submit
```

Comment: Fix second line in lev.jade: select(name="ansvarlig")

Comment: Sorry. Fixed. It's there in my original code.

Comment: can you check in browser what you are actually sending?

Comment: DenisFrezzato I thought you referred only to the missing parentheses. Had I only paid more attention to what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple and stupid white space error.

The select tag didn't get a name.

Changing to `select(name= "ansvarlig")` solved everything.